# Regex not matching unless the entire line is the same

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio-2010

I am having issues with regex. For example in the following code the if statement returns false:

```
string test("ABC123");
regex e("123");
if(regex_match (test.begin(), test.end(), e))
{
  //do something
}
```

The only way I can the regex to return true is if I set the regex to `"ABC123"` or `".+"`. Other possible regex such as `"[0-9]"` or `"[A-Z]"` also return false.

Answer (score 5):

No, see [this explanation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/):

> The entire target sequence must match the regular expression for this
>   function to return true (i.e., without any additional characters
>   before or after the match). For a function that returns true when the
>   match is only part of the sequence, see regex_search.

Use `regex_search` instead.

This returns `true`:

```
string test("ABC123");
regex e("123");
if(regex_search (test.begin(), test.end(), e))
{
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

`regex_search(test.begin(), test.end(), e))`

instead

regex_match will return true only if the entire string being tested matches the regex. regex_search otherwise will return true if a substring inside the string matches your.

please check this link for more information:

http://www.johndcook.com/blog/cpp_regex/